# Restrict connection to SQL Server By IP

Tags: sql-server

On a QA server I need to give access to specific login  from  just one IP to log to this server.

I wrote This login  trigger

```
Create   TRIGGER tr_CheckIP ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IPAddress NVARCHAR(50) ;
    If ORIGINAL_LOGIN()='test' 

    --print ORIGINAL_LOGIN() 
    begin


    SET @IPAddress = convert(NVARCHAR(50),ConnectionProperty('client_net_address'))
    --print @IPAddress
    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  IP
                    FROM    master..IPAddress
                    WHERE   IP = @IPAddress )
        BEGIN


            ROLLBACK 
        END
    End
END
```

However the trigger is preventing  the user from log although the IP exists in the IPAddress table.

Any idea where in the problem in the trigger

Comment: Firewalls are usually really good for filtering on IP addresses.

Comment: @kin thanks, the other post what i was looking for. i am in a problem now this trigger today is preventing any connection even as SA ..

Comment: @sebeid are you using the script that you posted or that one that I linked ?

Comment: @Kin the one you posted is working fine .. i am talking about the script  i posted .. but i was able to fix it i connected from SQLcmd and disable the trigger .. thanks  for considerations